# C Why Variable is unused?

Tags: c, debugging, variables

I just need some help debugging my program, how come my program tells me that I have an unused variable, but clearly I have it defined table mst[num_pt] right after I create the structure. Ive tried moving it around and defining it in other places as well as assigning mst[0] at other places but with no luck. Do I have a syntax error? The snippet of code that I am referring to is near the end but I thought it might help to have my entire program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *fp;
  int max_x, max_y, num_pt;
  int *x_coordinate, *y_coordinate;
  int inputfile = 0, outputfile = 0;
  int i;
  int count,dist,spot;
  char black[24],white[24];

  typedef struct{
    char colour[24];
    int x;
    int y;
    int pos;
  }table;

  strcpy(black,"black");
  strcpy(white,"white");
  if (argc == 1) {
    /* to generate random instances, accepting parameters from stdin */
    return 1;
  }
  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if (strcmp (argv[i], "-i") == 0)
      inputfile = i+1;
    else if (strcmp (argv[i], "-o") == 0)
      outputfile = i+1;
  }
  if (inputfile == 0) {
    printf("Error File does not exit!\n");
    return -1;
  }
  if ((fp = fopen(argv[inputfile], "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error name of file does not exist!\n");
    return -2;
  }
  while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &max_x) != 1) {
    if (ferror(fp)) {
      /* read error */
      printf("Error max value does not equal 1!\n");
      fclose(fp);
      return -3;
    }
    if (feof(fp)) {
      /* no integer to read */
      printf("Error no numbers to read in file!\n");
      fclose(fp);
      return -4;
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]"); /* skip the rest of line */
  }
  if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &max_y) != 1) {
    /* max_y not following max_x */
    printf("Error format for x not follwing y\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return -5;
  }
  while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &num_pt) != 1) {
    if (ferror(fp)) {
      /* read error */
      printf("Error num_pt != 1\n");
      fclose(fp);
      return -6;
    }
    if (feof(fp)) {
      /* no integer to read */
      printf("Error file is empty!\n");
      fclose(fp);
      return -7;
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]"); /* skip the rest of line */
  }
  x_coordinate = (int *)malloc(num_pt * sizeof(int));
  y_coordinate = (int *)malloc(num_pt * sizeof(int));
  for (i = 0; i < num_pt; i++) {
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &x_coordinate[i]) != 1) {
      if (ferror(fp)) {
    printf("Coordinate reading error!\n");
    /* read error */
    fclose(fp);
       return -8;
      }
      if (feof(fp)) {
    /* no integer to read */
    printf("Error no integers to read\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return -9;
      }
      fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]"); /* skip the rest of line */
   }
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &y_coordinate[i]) != 1) {
      /* y_coordinate not following x_coordinate */
      printf("Error x/y not following each other\n");
      fclose(fp);
      return -10;
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);

  for(count=0;count<num_pt;count++){
    strcpy(nodes[count].colour,white);
    nodes[count].pos = count;
    nodes[count].x = x_coordinate[count];
    nodes[count].y = y_coordinate[count];
  }
  table nodes[num_pt],parent[1],small[num_pt],mst[num_pt];
  mst[0] = nodes[0];
  strcpy(nodes[0].colour,black);
  parent[0] = nodes[0];
  for(spot=1;spot<num_pt;spot++){
    for(count=0;count<num_pt;count++){
      dist = (nodes[count].x-parent[0].x)+(nodes[count].y-parent[0].y);
      if (dist > 0 && strcmp(nodes[count].colour,white) == 0){
    small[0] = nodes[count];
      }
    }
    printf("Found node %d --> nodes %d to be closest\n",parent[0].pos,small[0].pos);
    parent[0] = small[0];
    mst[spot] = small[0];
    strcpy(nodes[small[0].pos].colour,black);
  }
  //int labelx=0,labely=0;

  /*
    if (outputfile > 0) {
    if ((fp = fopen(argv[outputfile], "w")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error, can't open print file\n");
    return -2;
      }
    fprintf(fp, "##################################################\n");
    fprintf(fp, "#%s\n", argv[inputfile]);
    fprintf(fp, "#area [0, MAX_X] x [0, MAX_Y]\n");
    fprintf(fp, "%d\t%d\n", max_x, max_y);
    fprintf(fp, "#number of points NUM_PT\n");
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", num_pt);
    fprintf(fp, "#coordinates\n");
    for (i = 0; i < num_pt; i++) {
      fprintf(fp, "%d\t%d\n", x_coordinate[i], y_coordinate[i]);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "#end of instance\n");
    fprintf(fp, "#Edges of the MST by Prim's algorithm:\n");

    fclose(fp);
 }
  */



  printf("Choosing point 0 as root ...\n");
  for (i = 1; i < num_pt; i++) {
    printf("Point %d has a distance %d to the tree, parent 0;\n", i,(abs(x_coordinate[0] - x_coordinate[i])) + (abs(y_coordinate[0] - y_coordinate[i])));
  }
  printf("#Edges of the MST by Prim's Algorithm\n");
  /*
  for(count=0;count<num_pt;count++){
    totalmst=totalmst+mst[count].dist;
    printf("%d %d %d\n",mst[count].coord[1],mst[count].coord[0],mst[count].dist);
  }
  printf("The total length of the MST is %d.\n",totalmst);
  */
  free(x_coordinate);
  free(y_coordinate);
  return 0;
}
```

The console returns:

```
ass2.c: In function ‘main’:
ass2.c:105:12: error: ‘nodes’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     strcpy(nodes[count].colour,white);
            ^
ass2.c:105:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
ass2.c:110:47: warning: variable ‘mst’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   table nodes[num_pt],parent[1],small[num_pt],mst[num_pt];
```

Comment: Don't you think it would make sense to tell us *which* variable? Please include the full error/warning message in your question.

Comment: Sorry, i just updated my question but it is mst[num_pt] that I am referring to.

Comment: And the exact message?

Comment: Should be updated now, my bad

Comment: `nodes` undeclared. lets solve this error first. As errors are more important then warnings :)

Comment: Isn't the message very clear? You set `mst` but never access it. If you disagree please point to the line where you actually use that variable (not just set).

Comment: The line under where I set the variables with "table nodes[num_pt],parent[1],small[num_pt],mst[num_pt]; I have a part where I want to assign node[0] to mst[0]. "  mst[0] = nodes[0];"

Comment: Yes, that is a set! But where do you read the `mst` value? There's no point setting a variable that is never used after that.

Comment: Ohhh, I see, so if I assign some place where I use "mst" then the error should go away?

Comment: @brzmath Don't ask us - try it out yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the `mst` issue.
Take care of the `nodes` issue and then worry about the subsequent errors.  Chances are the `mst` issue will disappear.

Also, you cannot declare arrays with runtime-determined sizes this way.
I expect if you increased your warnings (`-Wall` for `gcc`) you might get some more clarity on how what your seeing came to be.

Do something like this:
    table* nodes,small,mst;
    table parent[1];

```
nodes = malloc(sizeof(/* "whatever the things are in this array" */) * num_pt);
/*
 * Likewise for the other `table` arrays.
 */
```

Also, you seem to be using 2 different vars named `nodes`!
Check the loop right above your `table` array declarations.  Something ain't right here.

Comment: "you cannot declare arrays with runtime-determined sizes this way". Yes you can. Those are called [Variable Length Arrays (VLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: @kaylum - thanks for the lesson, and I think we are arguably both right.  Per the link you shared:  _"Programming languages that support VLAs include ..., C99 (although subsequently relegated in C11 to a conditional feature which implementations are not required to support; on some platforms, could be implemented previously with `alloca()` or similar functions)..."_